# Audiokit, turn off monitoring while using internal mic

Tags: swift, audiokit, avaudioengine

I'm using Audiokit to build a karaoke style app with a a recording feature in iOS. I'm playing music while the recording is taking place  to record both vocals and the music, which is working fine  I would like to turn off microphone monitoring while the user is recording on the device (without headphones), similar to the feature in Garageband. Would this be an AkSetting configuration?

I've tried setting AKBooster gain to 0 in various order, but I can't get it to record the vocals. 
Thanks in advance.

```
          do {
              try AKSettings.setSession(category: .playAndRecord, with: .allowBluetoothA2DP)
          } catch {
              AKLog("Could not set session category.")
          }

          AKSettings.defaultToSpeaker = true
          AKSettings.enableEchoCancellation = true


                mic = AKMicrophone()
                let tape = try? AKAudioFile()
                player = try? AKAudioPlayer(file: tape!)
                let beatFile  = try? AKAudioFile(readFileName: "candybeat.mp3")
                beatPlayer =  AKPlayer(audioFile: beatFile!)

                 mixer =  AKMixer(mic)
                 booster =  AKBooster(mixer)
                 mainMixer =  AKMixer(beatPlayer, booster, player)
                 AudioKit.output =  mainMixer
                 try? AudioKit.start()

                 recorder = try? AKNodeRecorder(node: mainMixer, file: tape)
```